# Way there is no google Recaptcha package for Flutter apps?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, recaptcha

I am looking for google recaptcha v2 package with checkbox to implement in my flutter app but there is no single one that offer this feature??
There is already in Android and IOS.
is there reason Flutter doesn't have one?

I found several ones but either outdated or not work as expected

Comment: Try this grecaptcha: ^0.0.6 - https://pub.dev/packages/grecaptcha

Comment: Or try g_recaptcha_v3: ^0.0.5 - https://pub.dev/packages/g_recaptcha_v3

Comment: this is just for android and not provide checkbox @Prashant

Comment: this is for web only and v3 not v2 @RisheekMittal

Comment: I wrote v3 only?

Answer (score 0):

Here try this one this one provides access to all the current captcha used by all the major players: [captcha_solver: ^1.0.4](https://pub.dev/packages/captcha_solver)

Comment: this isn't free it's paid

Answer (score 0):

There are many other ways to verify the human activity.

**You can generate 2 digit numeric value and place the mathematical operation between them and use it for Human Verification purpose.**

Comment: Could you explain it a bit better?